# Visual Studio 2015 cordova: deploy failed

Tags: android, cordova, wiki, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I have a problem while I'm trying to run my Cordova project on an Android device and Android emulators.

I'm using Visual Studio at the time.

The strange thing is that it works perfectly with ripple emulators.

```
All packages are already installed and there is nothing to restore.
NuGet package restore finished.
1>------ Build started: Project: test mobile, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.10.28 (x64) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\ApacheCordovaTools\packages\vs-tac
1>
1>  C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile>"C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\npm\\node_modules\vs-tac\vs-tac-cli.cmd"   build --platform Android --configuration Debug --projectDir . --projectName "test mobile" --npmInstallDir C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\npm --language en-US --buildTarget AndroidDevice
1>  ------ Cordova tools 4.3.0 already installed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\bld\Android\Debug
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\bin\Android\Debug
1>  ------    buildCommand: build
1>  ------    platform: Android
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: android
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: test mobile
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  ------    buildTarget: AndroidDevice
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------ Platform android already exists
1>  ------ Copying native files from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\native\android to platforms\android
1>  ------ Done copying native files to platforms\android
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  ------ Currently installed plugins: org.apache.cordova.device@0.3.0,org.apache.cordova.device-motion@0.2.11,org.apache.cordova.device-orientation@0.3.11
1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins:
1>  ------ Currently configured plugins: org.apache.cordova.device@0.3.0,org.apache.cordova.device-motion@0.2.11,org.apache.cordova.device-orientation@0.3.11
1>  ------ Preparing platform: android
1>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
1>  Calling plugman.prepare for platform "android"
1>  Preparing android project
1>  Processing configuration changes for plugins.
1>  Iterating over installed plugins: [ 'org.apache.cordova.device',
1>    'org.apache.cordova.device-motion',
1>    'org.apache.cordova.device-orientation' ]
1>  Writing out cordova_plugins.js...
1>  Wrote out Android application name to "test mobile"
1>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  splash screens: [{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png","density":"land-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-xhdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png","density":"port-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-xhdpi","platform":"android"}]
1>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\icons\android\icon-36-ldpi.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\icons\android\icon-48-mdpi.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\icons\android\icon-72-hdpi.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\icons\android\icon-96-xhdpi.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  Wrote out Android package name to "io.cordova.myapp76d7077ea38e4cd99a5883be4864bce5"
1>  ------ Copied C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\bin\Android\Debug\VSBuildInfo.xml to platforms\android\assets\www\VSBuildInfo.xml
1>  ------ Building platform: android
1>  Debug
1>  ------ Build configuration options: --debug
1>  Running command: cmd "/s /c ""C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat" --debug --ant ""
1>  ANT_HOME is set incorrectly or ant could not be located. Please set ANT_HOME.
1>  Built the following apk(s):
1>
1>  Command finished with error code 0: cmd /s /c ""C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat" --debug --ant "
1>  ------ Copying back to project: Android
1>  ------ Done copying compiled files: Android
2>------ Deploy started: Project: test mobile, Configuration: Debug Android ------
2>Starting launch process C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe "C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-tac\emulator.js" --platform android --path "C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile" --deployTarget "device" --language nl-NL --configuration debug  --cliVersion 4.3.0
2>  ------ Cordova tools 4.3.0 already installed.
2>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
2>  Calling plugman.prepare for platform "android"
2>  Preparing android project
2>  Processing configuration changes for plugins.
2>  Iterating over installed plugins: [ 'org.apache.cordova.device',
2>    'org.apache.cordova.device-motion',
2>    'org.apache.cordova.device-orientation' ]
2>  Writing out cordova_plugins.js...
2>  Wrote out Android application name to "test mobile"
2>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
2>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
2>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
2>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
2>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
2>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
2>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
2>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
2>  splash screens: [{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png","density":"land-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-xhdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png","density":"port-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-xhdpi","platform":"android"}]
2>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
2>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
2>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
2>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
2>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
2>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
2>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
2>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
2>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
2>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
2>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
2>  deleted: C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
2>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\icons\android\icon-36-ldpi.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
2>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\icons\android\icon-48-mdpi.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
2>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\icons\android\icon-72-hdpi.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
2>  copying image from C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\res\icons\android\icon-96-xhdpi.png to C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
2>  Wrote out Android package name to "io.cordova.myapp76d7077ea38e4cd99a5883be4864bce5"
2>  Running command: cmd "/s /c ""C:\Users\test\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\test mobile\test mobile\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat" --nobuild --device --debug""
```

After this in my build solution I get an error: deployment error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it only occurs when targeting to device and android emulator, this should be a known issue with Android SDK 24.3.2 used, which has been mentioned [in Known Issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/master/known-issues/known-issues-android.md).

If it is the case, please follow the instruction mentioned in the link to downgrade the android sdk tools to 24.2.

If it is not the case, go to visual studio menu Tools->Options-> Project and Solutions -> Select "Diagnostics" in MSBuild project build output verbosity. Then share the log for furthur investigation.